# I am unable to create new .txt file using StreamWriter Class

Tags: c#, streamwriter

Here is my code...

```
string path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE"), "Music", "stream.txt");

StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("stream.txt");
sw.WriteLine("i am stream");
sw.Close();
```

Comment: Why don't you ***use*** `path`? You currently are creating `stream.txt` in the same directory as your executable.

Comment: "unable" is not a very helpful error description. Please tell us what you expect this code to do, what happens instead, any error messages or exceptions? And as Rafalon asked: you create a `path` but never use it, instead you used `"stream.txt"` in `new StreamWriter()`. I guess that's your mistake.

Comment: Yes, use `new StreamWriter(path);`

Comment: I changed my code    string path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE"),
             "Music", "stream.txt");
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path);    Now it's working Thanx !

Comment: File.WriteAllText() is an easier way to do this.  Don't forget to dispose your writer.

Comment: @AlexK. though you're right that `File.WriteAllText()` is easier, OP already does `Dispose()` the stream, [`Close()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamwriter.cs,ab19992c30648b1d) is almost a synonym for `Dispose` in many classes like streams or db connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had the solution there:

```
string path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE"),"Music", "stream.txt");

            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path);
            sw.WriteLine("i am stream");
            sw.Close();
```

You just had to use the path variable you created :)

After execution remember to look in the Music folder for the `stream.txt` file

Answer (score 0):

Check This one:-

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Test 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
        string path = @"c:\temp\MyTest.txt";
        if (!File.Exists(path)) 
        {
            // Create a file to write to.
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path)) 
            {
                sw.WriteLine("Hello");
                sw.WriteLine("And");
                sw.WriteLine("Welcome");
            }   
        }

        // Open the file to read from.
        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path)) 
        {
            string s = "";
            while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.createtext(v=vs.110).aspx)